# Adjacency matrix clustering using spectral (cluster) network in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, cluster-analysis, spectral

I have the following dataset:

```
firm_id firm_id_
1         2
1         4
1         5
2         1
2         3
3         2
3         6
4         1
4         5
4         6
5         4
5         7
6         3
...
```

This data says for exampe that `firm_id` = 1 is directly connected to `firm_id` = 2, 4, and 5 and indirectly connected (within two paths) to `firm_id` = 3, 6, and 7. I can use some Python package like `networkx` to build the network of firm's connectivity. Now, I want to use Spectral Clustering (I guess this the correct methodology) to form clusters based on distance (number of edges separating each firm) and see how these clusters are connected to each other.

I would first define an adjacency matrix W of the above data. I then use [image] 
where *dist* is the distance between firm i and firm j, and c is a scale parameter to each element in W and then compute the Laplacian matrix (see [here](http://mikelove.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/spectral-clustering/) for example).

Now my question is can Spectral Clustering give me the link between each clusters and how far apart are the clusters (how many edges separate the clusters)? I was thinking to use [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_segmentation_toy.html#example-cluster-plot-segmentation-toy-py), the `scikit` package in Python but I have no idea how I can generate the links between clusters using `sklearn.cluster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community detection network is what I needed:

http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/

Answer (score 1):

For spectral clustering and these approaches to work well, you need to have *similarities*.

Your data seems to be solely a graph, i.e. edges that connect instances. You should be looking at **graph partitioning** and maybe community detection algorithms that work solely on the graph structure, and do not assume you have a continuous measure of similarity.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You are right. I don't have similarities. I only have linkages (where weight is always 1 between nodes that are connected). I decided to use this algo http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/ in python and I can form communities but I have no idea how the communities are connected. Would you have a suggestion to figure out how the communities would be connected?

Comment: I have no experience on this kind of data. All I've seen on social network analysis I found pretty much random, obvious or otherwise uninteresting.